# Integrate the unity AR project with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, unity-game-engine

I am working on an augmented reality project using vuforia unity extension. I created a project in unity 3d and export it for android platform. i **test the apk file**  on my device. and its working good. Now i want to use this inside my eclipse project. Fpr this purpose i followed the instructions from this link **https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/faq/unity-how-can-i-extend-unitys-android-activity#**
Butin the 4th step it says to browse to the project temp folder. i did the same. **But there is no staging area folder in temp folder**. 
what is the problem. is it a build issue or some unity version issue?

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Don't misuse it.

Answer (score 0):

you have to build the unity project again.
Then you can find  staging area folder.Hope it helpful for you.